# petapoco T4 template creating wrong poco

Tags: asp.net, petapoco

I am trying to use Petapoco in my asp.net web site. 
Following is my Database.tt

```
// Settings
ConnectionStringName = "Orgsetup";          // Uses last connection string in config if not specified
Namespace = "namespace";
RepoName = "myrepoName";
SchemaName = "orgSchema";
GenerateOperations = true;
GeneratePocos = true;
GenerateCommon = true;
ClassPrefix = "";
ClassSuffix = "";
TrackModifiedColumns = true;

// Read schema
var tables = LoadTables();


// Generate output
if (tables.Count>0)
{
  #>
   <#@ include file="PetaPoco.Generator.ttinclude" #>
  <# } #>
```

**and in my web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Orgsetup"    connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=dp_usermgmt;uid=root;pwd=xxxxxx;" 
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

After running this Database.tt ,I am getting a huge POCO Class with all Tables in all the Databases in the server.

I am using another two databases from the same server for the same application. That two working perfectly ...
This is a Mysql Server 5.5 .
Whats wrong with this

Comment: Don't use MySql myself, but one general hint, are you sure the credentials in the connection string are valid?

Comment: "Don't use MySql myself" ..
Please clear .. The credentials are correct  . the other two connections string shared the same credentials and working perfectly

Comment: Do you just get an empty file generated?

Comment: yes .. most of the time I am getting empty file ( with some header commented). Some times it generating POCOs

Comment: Any suggestions ... please i am struck up ... Most of the time I am  getting a blank .cs

Comment: No sorry - when I was getting blank files it was because the username in the connection string had wrong priviledges to see the schema.

Comment: But please notice i have getting POCOs if I retry a number of times. I have always select current project (see https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/issues/100) before runs the Database.tt

Comment: When you save the modified database.tt file it should give an error in the error list explaining what is happening. In VS 2012 you can now debug T4 templates by right clicking on them and selecting Debug T4 (i know this is old post but may help someone else lol)